# Find the volume(solid) , transform rectangular function to polar function

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, polar-coordinates, volume, solid-geometry

if want find volume of this problem

Under $ f(x)=x^2+y^2-4 $  and inside $ x^2 + y^2=9$ in plane  $z=0$

Can I use this integration in polar functions?

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_2^{3} (r^2 - 4) r dr\,d\theta.$$

Comment: You have the correct set-up, if you are trying to find the volume of the solid lying below the graph of $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-4$, inside the cylinder $x^2+y^2=9$, and above the plane $z=0$.

Comment: Yes , is de correct graph , thanks so much